# Same Vue component twice on same page duplicates component view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So what i am building is an application to view local IP camera streams. I have a component that streams the MJPEG streams over the network and then displays them in the component, MJPG.vue. This works just fine and as i expect it.

The problem i am facing is that once inside MJPG.vue, the user can click the streaming image to go into a secondary 'playback' mode that will let them access recorded data. So i need to essentially re-use the same MJPG.vue component within the playback view. The second instance of the MJPG.vue component doesnt behave correctly and is to some point an exact copy of the first instance. If i pause the playback of the first component, the second component instance pauses. If i pause the second instance, the first one in the background pauses.

Here is the confusing part. IF i manually hard-code a DIFFERENT camera stream into the second component instance, both of these components will stream independently of each other and work as expected. It seems like Vue is reusing the same instance twice instead of each instance of the component being its own.

MJPG.vue

```
<template>
<img ref="img" :src="img.src" style="border:1px solid white" height=500 width=500 />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    camera: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    aspectRatio: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isPlay() {
      return this.$store.state.DVR.isPlay;
    },
    .......
  },
  watch: {
    isPlay(n) {
      n ? this.play() : this.pause();
    },
    img(n, o) {
      if (o.src !== '') {
        // Old img has a real blob url, revoke it to clean up memory.
        URL.revokeObjectURL(o.src); // Must be done for garbage collection, or else memory leaks will form.
      }
      if (n.error === 204) {
        // Image didnt get sent back from the API/Error or problem with image?
        this.errorCount++;
      } else {
        this.errorCount = 0;
        this.setImgSize();
        this.imageBuffer.src = n.src; // Buffer image is so we can determine the real size of the frame received.
      }
    },
    layoutChanged() {
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.getWrapperSize();
        this.setImgSize();
      });
    },
    errorCount() {
      // There seems to be some problems with the stream, it could be down. We need to calculate how long to keep checking for images.
      if (this.errorCount * this.framerate >= this.timeout * 1000) {
        this.pause();
        this.streamDown();
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: true, // If the stream is loading or not.
      display: false, // Used in v-if to show the img to the user.
      img: '', // The src attribute of the image blob(blob:url) the user will see.
      timeout: 15, // Seconds until stream connection error timeout.
      errorCount: 0, // Stream error counter.
      isDown: false, // If the stream is believed to be down.
      backgroundWorker: null, // Background worker that handles the setTimeout lag issues.
      backgroundWorkerGW: null, // Background worker that handles the setTimeout lag issues.
      imageBuffer: new Image(), // Buffer image to collect received image sizes.
      imgHeight: 0, // Height of the image the user will see.
      imgWidth: 0, // Width of the image the user will see.
      imgRatio: null, // Then aspect ratio of the imageBuffer, used to calculate image size for its container.
      wrapperHeight: 0, // Wrapper div height.
      wrapperWidth: 0, // Wrapper div width.
      showOverflowOnActual: false, // Should the scrollbars be displayed on the image? Used for Actual image size setting.
      framerate: 0 // The framerate that the API is getting new images.
    };
  },
  mounted() {
      // Do some stream setup here...
  },
  methods: {
      // Streaming functions here...
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
.....
</style>
```

Comment: You are relying on the global state of `vuex` to determine when a DVR is being played. You have attached a watcher to observe changes to that variable, and each component will react to that.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy So any reference to the $store inside the component will trigger this observability duplication on all instances of that same component?

Comment: Yes. They're all watching that exact same variable. Consider using a unique variable in the store for each DVR.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy So in MJPG.vue i removed all references to Vuex($store) and its still the same behavior.